# Overloading = in bignum implementation

Tags: c++

I am writing a bignum implementation and in it I overloaded operators + and =. Here is my code that does it:

```
BigNum& operator+(const BigNum& b ) {
    BigNum sum;
    int carry=0;
    for (int i=0; i<N;i++){
        sum.dig[i]=(dig[i]+b.dig[i]+carry)%10;
        carry=(dig[i]+b.dig[i]+carry)/10;
    }
    return sum;
}

BigNum& operator=(const BigNum& rhs ) {
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        dig[i]=rhs.dig[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

They both seem to be working well on their own (I can assign a bignum to a bignum correctly and add two bignums correctly) but when I try to combine them I get answers that seem to be random. So if a and b are bignums, it's okay if I say

```
BigNum c=b;
```

and

```
cout<<a+b;
```

but

```
a=a+b;
```

gives an unexpected result.

Comment: What is `dig`?  How is it defined?  And can you give us some concrete example inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a reference to a local variable `sum` from your `+` operator. You can't meaningfully return references or pointers to local variables. Because of this error the behavior of your code is undefined, which the reason for your "unexpected results".

Since you are implementing a regular binary `+`, you have to return the result by value

```
BigNum operator +(const BigNum& b) const {
  BigNum sum;
  ...
  return sum;
}
```

As an additional note, binary `+` make more sense as a standalone (possibly friend) function, not as a class member. If you want to keep it as a class member, at least declare it `const` (see above).

A separate question is what `dig` is, what `N` is and whether your class violates the Rule Of Three. But it is impossible to say from what you posted.

Comment: I don't understand how this is different from my code, other than declaring is as const, which does not solve the problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @user132290: The return type is `BigNum`, not your `BigNum&`. You have to learn to see such little things if you want to program in C++.

Comment: Indeed, good catch.  The sad thing is that the compiler should have caught this without us needing to look at it.  Probably the OP doesn't have warnings and errors fully enabled yet.  He/she should do that ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question but I believe it will improve your code and as such, it's a "suggestion".

It would be wise to implement the + operator to create a temporary that invokes the += operator.

For example:

```
BigNum& operator += (const BigNum &other) {
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits_length; ++i) {
        int temp = digit[i];
        digit[i] = (digit[i] + other.digit[i] + carry) % 10;
        carry = (temp + other.digit[i] + carry) / 10;
    }
    return *this;
}

BigNum operator + (const BigNum& other) const {
    return BigNum(*this) += other;
}
```